# Getting array of IDs from html to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how can i get and loop deacTraining value in JS ?
in this given code, checkboxes's length is 0 after getting deacTraining's value.

html code snippet

```
<c:forEach var="acBatch" items="${batchBeanAll}" varStatus="loop">
<c:if test="${acBatch.getBatchStatus() == 'Active'}">
    <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}" scope="page"/>
    <tr>
        <td scope='col'><input id="deacTraining${loop.index }" type='checkbox' name='users'value='${acBatch.getBatchCode()}'/></td>
        <td scope='col'>${acBatch.getBatchDescription()}</td>
        <td scope='col'>${acBatch.getBatchSize()}</td>
        <td scope='col'>${acBatch.getBatchStatus()}</td>
    </tr>
</c:if>
```

```
<input value="Continue" type="submit" onclick="return checkDeactivateTraining();"/>
```

js code

```
<script>
function checkDeactivateTraining(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('deacTraining');
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
        if (checkboxes[i].checked)
            return true;
    }

    alert("Please select a training to deactivate.");
    return false;
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `name` of your checkboxes is `users`, the `id` is 'deacTraining...'.  Change:

```
document.getElementsByName('deacTraining');
```

to:

```
document.getElementsByName('users');
```

Comment: gosh. did not realize this one. i'll try using getElementsById

Comment: @Rjmr - since ids are required to be unique, this would not make sense. Moreover, `getElementById` exists, while`getElementsById` (note the 's') does not. :)

Comment: yes, getElementsById does not exist. can you suggest an alternative way for this?

Comment: uh, just use getElementsByName, but fix the name you're using to actually reflect the name of your checkboxes